# Dropbox core api for android:how to check if drpbox official app in installed on device

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I am developing an android app where user has to login in dropbox,the problem is that in browser activity user stucks on dropbox's [consent screen]
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402984/dropbox-core-api-for-android-activity-stops-after-authentication) .on pressing allow button the browser activity doesn't close .
Then i tried a dropbox app installed device,which removes the need of going through browser acitivity and returns dropbox key and secret so this directly can solve my problem .

So how could I know before starting my activity if device has dropbox app installed or not? Any api call I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to know the package name of dropbox app and then u can use this function to know whether it is installed or not :-

```
private boolean isInstalled(String pack) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed = false;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(pack, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,i will try and if works i will accept your answer.The package name i have to pass is "com.dropbox.android"?